# Generics in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux

What is the code enclosed in '<' and '>' near the `extends` keyword in the following code (coming from https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-utils-todomvc/js/components/TodoApp.react.js )

```
    class TodoApp extends Component<{}, {}, State> {
     static getStores(): Array<Store> {
       return [TodoStore];
     }

     static calculateState(prevState: ?State): State {
       return {
         todos: TodoStore.getState(),
         areAllComplete: TodoStore.areAllComplete(),
       };
     }

     render(): ?ReactElement {
       return (
         <div>
         <Header />
         <MainSection
          todos={this.state.todos}
         areAllComplete={this.state.areAllComplete}
       />
       <Footer todos={this.state.todos} />
      </div>
    );
   }
}
```

Comment: This is looks more like [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). Javascript is a dynamic language and as such has no need for generics.

Comment: I would definitely _not_ jump into React/Flux until you have a pretty good grip on Javascript fundamentals. It will only be frustrating/confusing.

Comment: @rossipedia don't worry about my frustration. Please look [here](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html#content) at the documentation. And if you can explain me what the <T> is.

Comment: I'm familiar with that documentation. The code you posted is not Javascript, it is most likely TypeScript, as I mentioned above, which is a strongly-typed language built on top of JavaScript which _does_ support generics.

Comment: @Derek doesn't look like JS to me too ( I'm quite decent ad JS ES5, not very into ES6), and i've completed a pair of (simple) projects in pure React.  But this syntax is on the docs of the official flux page.

Comment: It's Flow. See http://flowtype.org/docs/react-example.html

Comment: @rossipedia thank you.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin Thank you very much. Problem solved.